# I can't style h1 via CSS

Tags: html, css, heading

I just started with HTML and CSS. I went through the tutorial from html.net and now have a problem with CSS.

I want my headings (h1) to have its font-color to be white. It works if I write the CSS-Code inside the HTML-file but it don't work if I write the exact same code to my external CSS-file. I am pretty sure that I referenced the CSS-file correctly because I can style the labels and the body via the same CSS-file.

**style.css:**

```
<style>
h1 
{
    color: #FFFFFF !important;
}
label
{
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-family:consolas;
    font-size:120%;
}
body
{
    background-color:#AA5555;
}
</style>
```

support.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="de">
<head>
    <title>Support</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h1>Heading</h1>
        <label>Test</label>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The background-color of the body works. The styles of the label works. But not the forecolor of the heading h1. I've got only this CSS-file and I already tried it on several browsers (Chrome, Firefox, IE, Opera) with the same problem on every browser. I also tried to use h2/h3 instead but no chance to get this heading styled.

I even tried without the DTD and the xmlns. I need to understand what is going on and a solution for my problem. Do I need a specific version or something for CSS/HTML? I never worked with this stuff before and have no idea how to troubleshoot nor to fix it.

Thank you :)

Comment: remove <style> from your css file

Comment: Sounds to me like something is over-qualifying that rule; check for conflicting rules, in your browser dev tools, particularly those with `!important` declarations as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a `<style>` tag in the beginning of the css file. It's html, not CSS syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `<style>` tag in External file.it is not need.

Comment: why downvote???

Comment: because your first answer wasn't that one. you edited in your 5 min grace period

Comment: @dippas are there regulations against this?

Comment: ok,answer is updated,remove downvote.

Comment: the user just might downvoted at the time, and moved on..

Answer (score 1):

> style.css:
>
> ```
> <style>
> ```

And there’s your error ... HTML tags do not belong into any external stylesheet; *only* the CSS rules do.